# MariaDB sql trigger to update if key exists or insert if doesn't exist?

Tags: mysql, triggers, mariadb

I'm new to SQL, but trying to build a simple trigger that will execute on each insertion. I want it to update some table values if the key already exists, or insert it with some new values if it doesn't exist.

Below is what I have attempted, but I would ideally want tester to be the thing that is being inserted. Something like NEW.reference_key?

```
CREATE TRIGGER key_access_monitor 
BEFORE INSERT ON individual_key_log 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT reference_key FROM individual_key_log WHERE key = 'tester')
        SELECT 'Found it!'
    ELSE
    SELECT 'Cannot find it!'
   END IF
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to insert a new row if a row with the same key does not already exist, and update the existing row if it does exist, is that correct?

You'd probably find it easier to use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, as follows:

```
INSERT INTO individual_key_log
    (key, col1, col2, col3, ...)
  VALUES
    ('tester', 'val1', 'val2', 'val3', ...)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    SET col1 = 'val1', col2 = 'val2', col3 = 'val3', ...;
```

One of the problems with your trigger approach is that it is bad practice to attempt to query a table from within a row trigger on that same table, as it violates the ACID principle; many DBMSes do not permit it at all, raising a "Mutating Table" error. Updating a row from within an **insert row** trigger has the same problem magnified. A row trigger should never try to access its target table directly, instead accessing only the triggering row indirectly through **`OLD`** and **`NEW`**.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is pretty good, the only problem is I'm getting Can't update table 'individual_key_log' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger..

Comment: I meant to use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` *instead of* a trigger; it should be the actual **`INSERT`** query itself..

Comment: Ah, of course. That makes sense. Thanks for the input!